# AutoHotKey: How does the WinTitle work?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I just started playing around with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) today but got stuck at moving/resizing windows...
`WinMove` needs a `WinTitle` but I can't figure out how the `WinTitle` works.

When I try the following code:

```
#SingleInstance force 

#y::

run, notepad
Sleep, 1000
WinGetTitle, window,, A
MsgBox, Active window: %window%
Sleep, 1000
WinMove, window,, 0, 0
MsgBox, %window% moved.

return
```

Notepad dosn't get moved to the top left corner, but why?
I have also tried storing the ID as a string: `program := window` `WinMove, program,, 0, 0` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example "window" is a variable and "WinMove" is a command.

**Commands** always use "traditional syntax". Meaning: when you use a variable in a command, you have to enclose the variable in percent signs:

```
WinMove, %window%,, 0, 0
```

**EDIT:**

Btw.

WinGetTitle, window,, A

has to be

```
WinGetTitle, window, A
```

**EDIT2:**

```
#SingleInstance force 

#y::
run, notepad
WinWait, Untitled - Notepad ;  title - Use Window Spy to find the exact title of this window
; IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad, ,WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad
; WinWaitActive, Untitled - Notepad
Sleep, 200
WinMove, Untitled - Notepad,, 0, 0
return
```

Comment: It worked! But when I try with OBS-Studie 64-bit it doesn't work, but why? Then my editor is being moved instead of OBS. I'll changed `run, notepad` to `Run, C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OBS Studio\OBS Studio (64bit).lnk` and now it doesn't work...

Comment: Use Window Spy to find the exact title of this window and the commands WinWait, WinActivate and WinWaitActive before WinMove.

Comment: Could you make an example for me?

Comment: See EDIT2 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wouldn't it be a good idea to include `IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad, ,WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad` & `WinWaitActive, Untitled - Notepad` as a "backup" if notepad isn't active? (Since you wrote them as comments)

Comment: If you want to send more commands to this window as an active one, you should use this before sending each command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143220/discussion-between-mr-viggo-and-user3419297).